# Convert Office 365 classic team site template id (STS#0) to modern site template id (STS#3)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-template

In SharePoint Online, I have a classic team site. I know the steps to convert the look and feel to modern UI using modern site pages. However, the template id of the actual site i.e. "STS#0" is not changed.

Is there a way to convert the template id from "STS#0" to "STS#3" using PowerShell or any other method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, **you can not change site template of an existing SharePoint site**, it is by design.

We suggest that you can go to the [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/ct-p/SharePoint) to submit a feedback.

**Reference:**

- [Change site template of an existing site collection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/be4141cd-13e3-4556-8268-2f095771087d/change-site-template-of-an-existing-site-collection?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)